# NSURLConnection working properly on iOS 6 but not on earlier versions

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, ios6, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I initially created a project using XCode 4.5 but later i moved on the same code to XCode 4.2.

My code in running fine on all simulators including the latest iOS6, but on device its only works with iOS6 and NOT with the earlier versions.

When i send the request to the server with some parameters, it returns me an error 'Parameters missing'. (i think the way request created on iOS 5 and 6 are different, but not sure)

This is the code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [request setURL:requestURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"post"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type_id\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",type_poboq] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"signin_data\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonVal] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if(error.localizedDescription == NULL)
                               {
                                   NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                   [delegate ConnectionDidFinishLoading:returnString];
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                   [delegate ConnectiondidFailWithError:returnString];
                               }

                           }];
```

Comment: in which line is the error showing??

Comment: there is no error, the request (login request )goes successfully with iOS 6, but when i login with a device with iOS 5, the servers start sending 'Missing Parameters' message.

Comment: with iOS 6 server receives the JSON data i am sending from device successfully, but with iOS 5 it doesn't receive any JSON (only empty data).

Comment: i created a sample project with XCode 4.2 and used the same code, it worked perfect..... i think the reason NSURLConnection not working properly is because i created the project with XCode 4.5 but later started using it with XCode 4.2.

Comment: that should not be a problem if u do that until ur not using any ios6 features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently there was some problem with the boundary, i used the following line instead and it worked.

```
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
```